# Formatting percentage tick labels in seaborn catplot returning values higher than expected

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, seaborn, ticker

The x axis on my catplot currently consists of categorical decimal values as such:

```
[0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8. 0.9, 1.0]
```

I'm using the following to try to format to a percentage, but it's returning value values 10x greater than expected:

```
for axis in ax.axes.flat:
    axis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: f'{x:.0%}'))
    axis.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, p: f'{y:.2%}'))
```

currently yields:

```
[0, 100%, 200%, 300%, 400%, 500%, 600%, 700%, 800%, 900%, 1000%]
```

The y-axis is formatted correctly, not sure why the x-axis is returning values higher than expected.

[image: plot after label change]

Comment: I am afraid this is not reproducible without a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, seaborn plots categorical variables at `x=[0, 1, 2, ..., 10]`, so that's why the percentage formatter is returning `x=[0, 100, 200, ..., 1000]`.

In this case, you can apply the `%` f-string directly with `set_xticklabels`:

```
xticks = [0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]

for axis in ax.axes.flat:
    axis.set_xticklabels([f'{x:.0%}' for x in xticks])
    axis.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, p: f'{y:.2%}'))
```

Comment: Didn't realize seaborn assigned its own categorical axis. Remapping it to the custom list works. Would make sense why the 5% marker was being skipped. I suppose the next step is to derive it from the unique values within 'range' column itself in the event that they are ever change/added. Thanks!